# Need a way to avoid response messages in wcf service using BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, response, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF service which behaves as a listener from a master application residing over network.

I have used BasicHttpBinding and enabled ssl over it

Every time I send a request , the service sends a response => :P I know this is how it works

but for some function calls I don't want my service to send response message over network. Is it possible to disable response for few functions calls ?

I have tried the following code but this was not helpful

```
[OperationContract]
string TwoWayMessage(string message);
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void OneWayMessage(int x, int y);
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I would have commented but I dont have enough points yet.
But what do you get in return when the return type for your method being mapped is void?